# BS4 get info from class with weird name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Got this weird html from [the Steam Community market search](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid:730&start=0&count=3&currency=3&l=english&cc=pt):

```
<span class=\"normal_price\">$2.69 USD<\/span>
```

How to extract data with bs4? This is not working:

```
soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "\"normal_price\""})
```

Comment: Are you sure those quotes are in the *original HTML* and not shown because you printed a `repr()` of the string value?

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid:730&start=0&count=3&currency=3&l=english&cc=pt

Comment: You have HTML embedded in JSON. Parse the JSON *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have HTML embedded in a JSON string, which *must* escape the quotes. Rather than manually extract that data, parse the JSON first:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_data)
html = data['results_html']
```

If you are using the `requests` library, the response can be decoded for you:

```
response = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid:730&start=0&count=3&currency=3&l=english&cc=pt')
html = response.json()['results_html']
```

after which you can parse this with BeautifulSoup just fine:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid:730&start=0&count=3&currency=3&l=english&cc=pt').json()['results_html']
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find('span', class_='normal_price').span
<span class="normal_price">$2.69 USD</span>
```